# trying to create squidguard recipe in oe-core

Tags: security, embedded-linux, openembedded, recipe

[this picture contains the error log while creating the minimal image with  squidguard...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW0Y7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viJAU.png)

I copied the squidguard recipe from OE -Classic, and copied the files to new layer meta-demo. created the layer.conf file. When I try to build the image using bitbake command .... guidance needed . I not have knowledge about this ... { LIC_FILE_CHKSUM ???? }

Answer (score 0):

In your squidguard recipe, you should have this line:

`LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=c492e2.....ce9"`

The error log shows that md5 checksum has changed for COPYING file from squidguard to `17cccb557...e6` so you have to replace md5 part of LIC_FILES_CHKSUM variable:

`LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=17cccb557...e6"`

You can find here [squidguard_git.bb](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nefethael/meta-random/master/recipes-squidguard/squidguard/squidguard_git.bb) an example of squidguard recipe.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work ..

ERROR: /home/../squidguard-1.4.bb: squidguard-1.4: LIC_FILES_CHKSUM contains an invalid URL: md5= "17cccb557...e6"
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/../squidguard-1.4.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable do_fetch[file-checksums], expression was ${@bb.fetch.get_checksum_file_list(d)}  ${@get_lic_checksum_file_list(d)} which triggered exception BBHandledException:

Comment: You have to replace 17cccb557...e6 by the complete md5 `17cccb55725bad30d60ee344fa9561e6` from the error log, i didn't type the whole thing.

Comment: Can you paste your recipe ?

Comment: http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded/tree/recipes/squidguard/squidguard_1.4.bb

I Edited the file by adding 

BB_STRICT_CHECKSUM = "0"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "17cccb55725bad30d60ee344fa9561e6"

ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN}-tools ='1'

Comment: if i am trying to create recipe , how long time will take to finish this ? 
for beginners and experienced person .....

Comment: Correct syntax is 

`LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = " \                    
 file://COPYING;md5=17cccb55725bad30d60ee344fa9561e \
"`

I suggest you to look at devtool to create recipes, this video is really instructive https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiD7rB35CRE

Comment: i followed the steps mentioned in the video . when i try to build the squidguard recipe getting following error

` ERROR: Task (poky/workspace/recipes/squidguard/squidguard_1.4.bb:do_conf‌​igure) failed with exit code '1' ` `ERROR: squidguard-1.4-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-‌​gnueabi/squidguard/1‌​.4-r0/temp/log.do_co‌​nfigure.19012)`  `ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-‌​gnueabi/squidguard/1‌​.4-r0/temp/log.do_co‌​nfigure.1901`

Comment: multiple problems on this recipe: recipe makefiles are not working with separate src/build, so you have to use `inherit autotools-brokensep`. Your do_configure error is due to include/lib poisioning, and is fixed by adding  `--with-ldap-inc=${STAGING_INCDIR} --with-ldap-lib=${STAGING_LIBDIR}`.
I added the recipe here: `https://github.com/nefethael/meta-random/tree/master/recipes-squidguard/squidguard`
I added only configure/compile stuff, maybe it needs to customize do_install() step.

Comment: when try to bulid it i am getting the following error : 
`ERROR: squidguard-1.0+git999-r0 do_configure: autoreconf execution failed.`
`ERROR: squidguard-1.0+git999-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/babu/oe-core/build/tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/squidguard/1.0+git999-r0/temp/log.do_configure.6177)`
`ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ../tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/squidguard/1.0+git999-r0/temp/log.do_configure.6177`

Comment: You should add your failed log.do_config‌​ure file, and maybe config.log from build folder.

Comment: When bitbake fails with `ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: ../tmp-glibc/work/armv7at2hf-neon-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/squ‌​idguard/1.0+git999-r‌​0/temp/log.do_config‌​ure.6177`, we need to see `log.do_config‌​ure.6177` file to have details on error. As it is a configure problem, you should also provide `<build>/tmp/work/<arch>/squidguard/<version>/git/config.log` to get help. You also can join #yocto on freenode chat.